# Handling time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a win-32 application we simply used Regional settings on the PC to indicate to the application both time zone and language. How is this done in rails or web apps in general? 
So for example if a doctor sees the time of his patient chart in France he should see it at local time? right?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches, but here are a couple of examples;

- A local doctor keeps his schedule online, and he does not need to interact with anyone else in the system, he just wants to enter and see his own schedule.
  In this case, just storing the times in local time would most likely be simplest, since no conversion is necessary. Why complicate things un-necessarily?
- A video conference reservation system that can book meetings spanning multiple time zones.
  In this case, storing times in UTC and converting to/from UTC in the web application (ie from local time to UTC when a time is entered, from UTC to local time when the schedule is presented) is probably the way to go. UTC is unique (ie a time only happens once since there is no DST) and fairly easily converted to and from local times.

If you can keep to either of the two above, storing UTC or local time, things are fairly straight forward. Speaking from experience, if you need to mix them, things can get *very* complicated.